# How to fix DIV hidden from SVG Object?

Tags: html, css, svg

When i have an SVG under Object tag anything under the Object tag i cant show, in this case class .card_middle and it's content wont show up :(

I have the full files with SVG in Github: 
https://github.com/MariuzM/SVG-Anime-Test

I need to use this as an Object tag because i have animation going on within the SVG file.

```css
.card_top {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card_middle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card_bottom {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}


/* .pic4 {
    background-image: url('pic4.svg');
    min-height: 100%;
    } */
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha256-azvvU9xKluwHFJ0Cpgtf0CYzK7zgtOznnzxV4924X1w=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha256-K0KkaRh1fs/UYfKcnzBK9G/X7HgzuaeVI1hJPS8Sxs4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<body>
  <div class="card card_top" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      Card top
    </div>
  </div>

  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="pic4.svg">
        <div class="card card_middle" style="width: 18rem;">
          <div class="card-body">
            Card Middle
          </div>
        </div>
      </object>

  <div class="pic4" src="pic4.svg">
    <div class="card card_bottom" style="width: 18rem;">
      <div class="card-body">
        Card bottom
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I answered your question but I'm curious, why you need `object` tag for animated `SVG`? Animated `SVG`s will work in most browsers by default.

Comment: because i have some JS running in the SVG file when i'm using something else like src to point to SVG file, the animations don't run :( but i think in this case i've solved this by having the background svg as separate file and loading that file as normal src and then just loading object with animation as a div next to my desired div

Comment: Mark thanks for cleaning up will try to keep this in mind. Also i did add a . between css and html i was not able to separate them without the .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code that you put inside the `<object>` tag will be used only if the browser fails to show the object itself.

In your case, you have a `SVG` file as a source of `<object>` and some html inside the `<object>` tag itself; so if browser fails to show the `SVG` file, the content of `<object>` will be visible to user instead.

[w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H53.html) says:

> Fallback content for the object element is only available to the user
>   when the media loaded by the element is not rendered by the user agent...